# How to use foreach inside <<<END, PHP

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, foreach

i have the following code with variable and text inisde for sending a form. My problem is that I cant figure out how to execute php inside that text, for example foreach function.

```
$somearray;

$variable = <<<END

Hello world foreach($somearray as $v){echo $v} //this does not work of course in my case.

END;
```

you help would very much appreciated.
thank you

Comment: can you show us a sample output?

Comment: Eugh. That's horrible. Just prepare your data before you create your string. `$v = implode('', $somearray); $variable = "Hello world $v";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<<<END` & `END;` are synonymous with using quotations marks, just less the use of `\"` 100 times. You can't execute code within a string, you'll need to concatenate the results instead.

What you're trying to do is basically this:

```
$variable = "foreach($somearray as $v) echo $v;";
```

When really you most likely want this:

```
$variable = "";
foreach ($somearray as $v) $variable .= $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<<<` syntax is a multi-line string format. Everything inside the block is part of a string. You cannot have any PHP code in there.

If you need to have a looped block in there, you would need to generate that string before the `<<<` block as a variable, and include it in the string that way.

```
$ins = '';
foreach($myarray as $val) {$ins .= "blah, {$val}, etc, ";}

$variable = <<<END
    Hello world {$ins}
END;
```

(I'd also note that in the simple example you gave, the `foreach()` could just as easily use `implode()`)